# calendar.events.insert returning undefined on callback

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to insert envet through googleapis.
But the calendar.evnets.insert retruning undefined on the callback, 
But the error is also null,
I am not getting any data on callback, But fortunately the event is being added on the calendar.

Comment: Please edit your question include your code and the full error message

Comment: If the event is created, the error is null and the callback is undefined, it looks like the code is mishandling the callback response. To further help you, please share the code that calls the API and handles the callback.